# In Latin, is there a difference between C and Q?

Tags: pronunciation

In Latin, what is the difference of sounds made by C and Q? The almost sound the same to me. Is there something, I'm missing here

Comment: Any basic resource will tell you the answer to this. The letter <c> represents /k/, while <qu> represents /kʷ/ (<q> is not used on its own in Latin, except in abbreviations). The difference is the same as between _kick_ and _quick_ in English, do those sound the same to you as well?

Comment: What about the answers to your previous question about this isn't clear to you?

Comment: I agree with @Cairnarvon. If you engage with us in the comments, we can better help you clarify what's left unclear to you. But so far it looks like you're asking the same type of questions: why do we have C and Q, and (now) what can we do about it? The former has been answered before, and the latter is off-topic on StackExchange, since it's an opinion question.

Answer (score 3):

The letter C represents IPA `/k/`, while the letter Q (or rather the digraph QU) represents IPA `/kʷ/`. As Janus said in the comments, it's like the difference between "**k**ick" and "**qu**ick" in English.

This difference is as important in Latin as it is in English, distinguishing word pairs like ***c**ibus* "food" vs ***qu**ibus* "to which ones".

Comment: And let's not forget the difference between *qui*, pronounced /kʷi/ and *cui*, pronounced /'kuj/.